# Output reordering using "File::Copy"

Tags: perl

Consider the following code, where `test2.txt` contains the text `Text2` (and trailing newline).

```
use File::Copy;

open (my $fh, "|-", "cat");
print $fh "Test1\n";

copy("test2.txt", $fh);

close $fh;
```

I expect this to print:

```
Test1
Test2
```

However, the following is being printed:

```
Test2
Test1
```

Why is this occurring, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Turn on autoflush (IIRC it's `$| = 1`) and see what happens.

Comment: I figured that might help, but even if it does I'm not sure if that's just because I'm getting lucky. I don't want the program to work on a Dev/Test system and then fail on prod due to some buffering issue affected by load.

Comment: What I suspect is happening is that the two output mechanisms are using different sets of buffers, and with autoflush off the `close $fh` is flushing first, then the `cat` process flushes when it gets closed.

Comment: Also, it's probably a really bad idea to depend on this type of thing working in general. I suspect this will always be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing buffered and unbuffered IO, never a good idea.  (File::Copy uses sysread/syswrite and its own buffer between the two.)

You are much better off just doing:

```
use File::Slurp 'read_file';

print $fh read_file('test2.txt');
```

though I do wonder why you are piping to cat and if you really want that to be buffered at all.

Comment: Thanks, although my solution is to replace `print` above with `syswrite`.